# XML formatter that can group

Tags: xml, formatting, grouping

I have an XML file like this:

```
<site="X">
 <function="DATA">
   <address>10.0.0.0/24></address>
 </function>
</site>
<site="X">
 <function="DATA">
   <address>10.2.0.0/24></address>
</function>
</site>
<site="X">
 <function="VOICE">
   <address>10.4.0.0/24></address>
 </function>
</site>
.... other entries
```

and i want it to be grouped together like:

```
<site="X">
 <function="DATA">
   <address>10.0.0.0/24></address>
   <address>10.2.0.0/24></address>
 </function>
 <function="VOICE">
   <address>10.40.0.0/24</address>
 </function>
```

Any ideas how to do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use XSLT in order to perform the grouping of related records based on `site` and `function` elements and it's subsequent transformation. The following XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:key name="siteKey" match="site" use="@a"/>
    <xsl:key name="functionKey" match="function" use="concat(parent::site/@a, '|', @b)"/>   

    <xsl:template match="s">    
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:for-each select="site[generate-id(.)=generate-id(key('siteKey',@a)[1])]">
                <xsl:copy>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="@a"/>                
                    <xsl:for-each select="key('siteKey', @a)">                  
                        <xsl:for-each select="./function[generate-id(.)=generate-id(key('functionKey',concat(parent::site/@a, '|', @b))[1])]">
                            <xsl:copy>
                                <xsl:copy-of select="@b"/>
                                <xsl:copy-of select="key('functionKey', concat(parent::site/@a, '|', @b))/address"/>
                            </xsl:copy>
                        </xsl:for-each>     
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </xsl:copy>
            </xsl:for-each>        
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template> 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to this input
(note: I have edited the xml you provided, in order to become valid):

```
<s>
<site a="X">
 <function b="DATA">
   <address>10.0.0.0/24</address>
 </function>
</site>
<site a="X">
 <function b="DATA">
   <address>10.2.0.0/24</address>
</function>
</site>
<site a="X">
 <function b="VOICE">
   <address>10.4.0.0/24</address>
 </function>
</site>
</s>
```

Produces this output:

```
<s>
    <site a="X">
        <function b="DATA">
            <address>10.0.0.0/24</address>
            <address>10.2.0.0/24</address>
        </function>
        <function b="VOICE">
            <address>10.4.0.0/24</address>
        </function>
    </site>
</s>
```

Further reading on XSLT grouping: http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html

Comment: see feedback below

Answer (score 0):

This fails for the following input:

```
<s>
<site a="X">
 <function b="DATA">
   <address>10.0.0.0/24</address>
 </function>
</site>
<site a="X">
 <function b="VOICE">
   <address>10.2.0.0/24</address>
</function>
</site>
<site a="Y">
 <function b="VOICE">
   <address>10.4.0.0/24</address>
 </function>
</site>
</s>
```

it gives:

```
<s>
   <site a="X">
      <function b="DATA">
         <address>10.0.0.0/24</address>
      </function>
      <function b="VOICE">
         <address>10.2.0.0/24</address>
         <address>10.4.0.0/24</address>
      </function>
   </site>
   <site a="Y"/>
</s>
```

http://xsltransform.net/jxDigV9/3

Comment: You are right. I have updated my answer to take the parent site into account when creating function keys.